# How to add one to a cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

My goal is to add 1 to a cookie, once a button is clicked. My code looks like this:

```
    console.log("Checking for any existing cookies...");
    var ifcookie = $.cookie('searchcount');
    if (ifcookie >= 0) {
        var count = $.cookie('searchcount');
        const one = 1;
        var count = count + one;
        console.log("Total searches: " + count);
        $.cookie('searchcount', count, { expires: 99999 });
        var count = $.cookie('searchcount');
        console.log(count);}}
```

So basically every time function "countSearches" is executed, I want to add 1 to the cookie "searchcount". 
But my output is just "0111...". How can I add this and set this to a cookie?

I use jquery for the cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

```
 var count = count + one;
```

to

```
var count = parseInt(count) + one;
```

The [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function parses a string argument and returns an integer. The value of the cookie is a string, not a number.